# RestSharp JSON Parameter Posting

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, restsharp

I am trying to make a very basic REST call to my MVC 3 API and the parameters I pass in are not binding to the action method.

**Client**

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.Resource = "Api/Score";
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

request.AddBody(request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { A = "foo", B = "bar" }));

RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

**Server**

```
public class ScoreInputModel
{
   public string A { get; set; }
   public string B { get; set; }
}

// Api/Score
public JsonResult Score(ScoreInputModel input)
{
   // input.A and input.B are empty when called with RestSharp
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

You don't have to serialize the body yourself. Just do

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddJsonBody(new { A = "foo", B = "bar" }); // Anonymous type object is converted to Json body
```

If you just want POST params instead (which would still map to your model and is a lot more efficient since there's no serialization to JSON) do this:

```
request.AddParameter("A", "foo");
request.AddParameter("B", "bar");
```

Comment: Both. The second approach is much faster though.

Comment: You can do `AddObject(new { A = "foo", B = "bar" })` too which takes the object properties and converts them into parameters

Comment: what if element name contains dash (-)?

Comment: Use [SerializeAs] for XML, or whatever JSON.NET uses to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: For those that want to jsonize themselves:
`request.AddParameter("text/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);`

Comment: @KylePatterson you can also implement your own ISerializer and set RestClient.JsonSerializer to use it.

Comment: @JohnSheehan perhaps this is a recent change, but the JsonSerializer is set on the RestRequest, not the RestClient. RestClient has a Deserializer, but it's set using AddHandler.

Comment: There's one obsolete parantheses after the `request.AddBody(new ...` in your first example.

Comment: AddHeader and AddBody didn't work, but AddParameter method @KylePatterson suggested, works. Weird!

Comment: For me, using the AddParameters caused an internal server error. I had to use the first method.

Comment: How to attach file to this request?

Comment: deprecated/doesnt work for json (it's defaulting to xml??), use AddJsonBody()

Comment: what's the syntax if json(dict) contains an array?

Comment: I'm calling a vendor's API and AddParameter succeeds, but AddJsonBody fails. Is it possible they coded their API that I can only use AddParameter?

Answer (score 68):

In the current version of RestSharp (105.2.3.0) you can add a JSON object to the request body with:

```
request.AddJsonBody(new { A = "foo", B = "bar" });
```

This method sets content type to application/json and serializes the object to a JSON string.

Comment: How to attach file to this request?

Comment: how do you name the object? eg. if you need to send "details" : { "extra" : "stuff" } ?

Comment: @OPV You can add a file to the request like this: request.AddFile(pathToTheFile);

Comment: @mdegges If you are using an anonymous class as the body to have the JSON look like your example setup the RestSharp Request like this: 

`var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("http://your.api.com");
var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("do-something", Method.POST);
var body = new {details = new {extras = "stuff"}};
request.AddJsonBody(body);
var response = client.Execute(request);`

Answer (score 51):

This is what worked for me, for my case it was a post for login request :

```
var client = new RestClient("http://www.example.com/1/2");
var request = new RestRequest();

request.Method = Method.POST;
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter("application/json", body , ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

body :

```
{
  "userId":"sam@company.com" ,
  "password":"welcome" 
}
```

Comment: How do you insert the body into your c# code ? as string body = "{
  "userId":"sam@company.com" ,
  "password":"welcome" 
}"; does not work.

Comment: You should use "" instead of "    string body = @" { ""userid"", ...     "

Comment: If I have  " var myJSON = "{ JSON Content }" , then what changes I have to make in AddParameters ?

Answer (score 15):

Hope this will help someone. It worked for me -

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://www.example.com/");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("login", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
var body = new
{
    Host = "host_environment",
    Username = "UserID",
    Password = "Password"
};
request.AddJsonBody(body);

var response = client.Execute(request).Content;
```

Comment: Looks like `request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `List` of objects, you can serialize them to JSON as follow:

```
List<MyObjectClass> listOfObjects = new List<MyObjectClass>();
```

And then use `addParameter`:

```
requestREST.AddParameter("myAssocKey", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfObjects));
```

And you wil need to set the request format to `JSON`:

```
requestREST.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to Deserialize your anonymous JSON type from the request body.

```
var jsonBody = HttpContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
ScoreInputModel myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ScoreInputModel>(jsonBody);
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is complete console working application code. Please install RestSharp package.

```
using RestSharp;
using System;

namespace RESTSharpClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string url = "https://abc.example.com/";
        string jsonString = "{" +
                "\"auth\": {" +
                    "\"type\" : \"basic\"," +
                    "\"password\": \"@P&p@y_10364\"," +
                    "\"username\": \"prop_apiuser\"" +
                "}," +
                "\"requestId\" : 15," +
                "\"method\": {" +
                    "\"name\": \"getProperties\"," +
                    "\"params\": {" +
                        "\"showAllStatus\" : \"0\"" +
                    "}" +
                "}" +
            "}";

        IRestClient client = new RestClient(url);
        IRestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/properties", Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; CHARSET=UTF-8");
        request.AddJsonBody(jsonString);

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        //TODO: do what you want to do with response.
    }
  }
}
```