# Mixing parameters in RestSharp request

Tags: restsharp

Assume following in .NET MVC controller:

```
 public JsonResult Update(string param1, User user)
    {
        //Some code here
        return null;
    }
```

How would one use RestSharp to do post to this method?

This does not work (controller gets empty user):

```
    var request = new RestRequest("Update", Method.POST);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddParameter("param1", "whatever");
    request.AddBody(user); //Instance of User
    _restClient.Execute(request);
```

However it will work if controller would have only one parameter "user"

So is this possible to mix parameters in RestSharp?

Comment: Have you tried request.AddBody(request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(user)) ?

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312970/restsharp-json-parameter-posting?rq=1 AddBody does it on its own

Comment: Did you inspect the request on the controller? Maybe the model binder cannot figure out how to map the params to User.