# RestSharp - Serializing an @ symbol

Tags: c#, json, serialization, restsharp

Using RestSharp 105.2.3

The API I am talking to requires use to send in a json body, but with a `@c` symbol as part of the field name. This is illegal in C# of course so I can't just use a dynamic object like below.

Is there a way to get the `"@c"` in the field name?

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://aaa.bbb.com");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddJsonBody(new
        {
            @c=".Something",
            username="johnsmith"
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried approaches from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312970/restsharp-json-parameter-posting)?

Comment: did my approach work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a string like this:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://aaa.bbb.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

string json = "{\"@c\":\".Something\", \"username\":\"johnsmith}";
request.AddJsonBody(json);
```