# How to pass values to inside the json using RestClient

Tags: c#, rest, django-rest-framework

How we can pass value to details section in  below Josn

JSON File

```
{
  "firstName": "JB000123",
  "LASTNAme": "SHP0000123",
  "details": [
    {
      "a": "Full Trucking Load",
      "b": "2",
      "c": "USD"
    },
    {
      "a": "Ocean Freight",
      "b": "2",
      "c": "USD"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to add records in Details part

```
var client = new RestClient(URL);
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(Username, Password);
var request = new RestRequest("/xyz/xyzz/", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("firstName", "Test"); 
request.AddParameter("LASTNAme", "Tets Last Name"); 
request.AddParameter("details", ???); 

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
```

Comment: No, I have assign values in "FirstName" and "Lastname" but not able to  pass value in details section, when its successfully validate i will get output in Content variable

Comment: Unless my understanding is incorrect, you're currently building a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body (based on [the docs here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest)), meaning that the data will be sent like `firstName=JB000123&LASTNAme=SHP0000123`. I'm not sure how you would pass complex objects in this format since you haven't specified how the server will be handling it. You'll need to work that out first.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312970/restsharp-json-parameter-posting) might help?

Comment: What does your endpoint expect as param, a 'details' object, or an array of objects?

Comment: Thank you, solved.